# Can not fetch instanceTree autodesk

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError:> Cannot read property 'getRootId' of undefined
even i am using  Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT..still no effect.

Comment: Which version of the viewer are you using? It's recommended to use v2.16 above, viewingService (View and Data API) is expried now. See there for more detail, https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-giving-error-403-unauthorized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wait for `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` to be fired when you want to access the `instanceTree`:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, function () {

  var instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree //cool
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `instanceTree` data structure, but yet the functions/operations, which are the supported way. If your need is to enumerate leaf nodes, try something similar to as [described here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/enumerating-leaf-nodes-viewer):

```
function getAllLeafComponents(viewer, callback) {
    var cbCount = 0; // count pending callbacks
    var components = []; // store the results
    var tree; // the instance tree

    function getLeafComponentsRec(parent) {
        cbCount++;
        if (tree.getChildCount(parent) != 0) {
            tree.enumNodeChildren(parent, function (children) {
                getLeafComponentsRec(children);
            }, false);
        } else {
            components.push(parent);
        }
        if (--cbCount == 0) callback(components);
    }
    viewer.getObjectTree(function (objectTree) {
        tree = objectTree;
        var allLeafComponents = getLeafComponentsRec(tree.getRootId());
    });
}
```

Comment: `function waitForElement(){                                   
           if(instanceTree.getRootId() !== "undefined"){... }
                        else{
                            setTimeout(waitForElement, 250);
                        }
                    };`

Comment: or `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT`?

Comment: the problem was like javascript was not waiting until the geometry load ..I have settled it by waiting function like i mentioned and it is resolved ..I can try the solution provided by you ..But my whole code is dependent in instance tree and I don't want to change it right now..Thanks though.